# Is there a correct way to make image icon/buttons for iOS apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, image, adobe-illustrator

So I'm building my app in Swift for iPhone only.

When I want custom image buttons, I create my own image icons for these buttons. I design them as vectors in Adobe Illustrator CS6 and save them as high quality PNG 24 bit.

But my image icons never appear to be very good quality. (I am only comparing this to other apps images. For example:

**Icons in eBay app: Nice a crisp/sharp**

[image]

**Icons in Amazon app: Nice a crisp/sharp**

[image]

**Then here are the icons taken from my app:**

[image]

[image]

You can see from the above 'social' icons, that if I just try and make the stroke lines thinner, then they just appear incredibly faint.

All images above are taken as screenshots from my actual device. The icons you see in my app are being shown at roughly 30x30 or 50x50

**My questions are:**

Am I created these icons wrong?

What size, specs should I be creating these icons as?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you use retina images ?

Comment: the problem probably is the *"roughly"* part - the images will look best when displayed at their exact resolution.

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo So I believe I am using retina images. I created the icon at an original size of 2469x2469. I then use an OSX app called Prepo - which created for me the "@2x and @3x" resolutions and names them accordingly. These are all in my Assets folder inside of xcode. Does that sound correct?

Comment: That looks correct : your "@2x" image should be twice bigger than the normal one and the "@3x" three time bigger. Try having your icons size conforming to the Apple guidelines provided by @marchiore, thus there will no be rescaling

Comment: @luk2302 So are you saying, that If i need to display and image in my app at 50x50 - then I should just create the image at 50x50 in Illustrator. Or should I create much higher than that - say 2048x2048, and then set the size of it in xcode in the inspector tab in storyboard?

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo So that's how they show, my original is at 2469, the '@2x' is at 1646 and the normal is at 823. But Do you know what the best way/size for me to create them is? The apple documents don't really help, as all it says is "About 66 x 66" for a toolbar icon - So does that mean I create the icon at 198x198 (3x) or do I create it at say 1000x1000? I've tried both ways and the best I can seem to get them is how you see in the image in my original question.

Comment: Having over-scaled image is unnecessary : the auto rescaling is not necessary great and it improves greatly the size of your app. You can work on a 1000px or vectorial image at first, but when you save it in order to be used, use the resolution provided by apple (e.g 33x33 for standard, 66x66 for retina "@2x", etc...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this [iOS Human Interface Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html).

It show all the formats and size for all devices